# Android Studio Project: bottom of UI is cut off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imagebutton

I'm having a problem with the bottom of my ListView and ImageButton being cut off when I load my app onto a phone or when using an emulator.  I could just use margins or padding, but wouldn't that be device specific?  I'd like my app to look as I want it to regardless of screen size.  Here is my code:

The Class:

```
public class Cookbook extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] items = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.row_layout,
                        items);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_cookbook, container, false);
        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
    }
}
```

The Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#f9e48f" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The Android Studio preview looks like this:

[image: Android Studio Preview]

But when emulating it or loading it onto a phone, it looks like this:

[image: Emulated UI display]

Comment: It seems that the screenshots you've added are different, where the tabs came from?

Comment: put your main activity xml where you push fragment from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using `CoordinatorLayout` with `ListView`. You can change your implementation to `RecyclerView` to achieve correct scroll.

or If you are tagetting above 5.0, you can use the following piece of code

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true); 
}`

I think `CoordinatorLayout` only works with the children of [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html).

Comment: I changed the layout to Relative and set the ViewPager to be set below the appbar.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me before recently.  I recommend posting your `styles.xml` as well.

The culprit for me was this line of code or something similar:

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

Here's the Question I posted with a similar issue:
[Layout is under StatusBar and Soft Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128482/layout-is-under-statusbar-and-soft-keys)

Answer (score 0):

In `Android Design Library`, well, the `FloatingActionButton` supposed to be within the `CoordinatorLayout`, not within any other views ex: a Fragment view in one of the tabs above. so try adding your `FloatingActionButton` to your `main_layout` and then just communicate with the activity to show/hide the `FAB` and do the necessary clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in onCreateView, I think it will work.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the layout to RelativeLayout worked for me. Then added this line in viewPager tag :

```
android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
```

Voilla..!!