# Toolbar doesn't hide on list scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-tabs

So, I have this main activity layout using `CoordinatorLayout` to display a toolbar and tabs below it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            local:tabMode="fixed"
            local:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/header_shadow"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then I have 2 fragment layouts, each for each of the 2 tabs I'll have. One fragment displays a `ListView` on its content:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/header_shadow"
    tools:context=".StationsFragment">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/stations_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want my toolbar to hide when I scroll the listview above, and it should be ok with the code I have, at least from what I read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767691/1959761), but it's not working. At the moment I've tried to remove the `FrameLayout` from the fragment activity but that didn't solve the issue. I've considered hard coding the scroll event from the listview but if possible I really want this to be working with no code behind..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Humm try with layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" in your xml

Comment: @Coeus didn't work :/, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `CoordinatorLayout` with `ListView`. You can change your implementation to `RecyclerView` to achieve correct scroll.

check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33489533/726625). This may help you.

Comment: so it is impossible to achieve this with `ListView` unless hard coding the scroll event, right? I'm using ListView because I've never worked with the `RecyclerView`, but it seems I'll have to use it..

Comment: Thats true. we have to move on to `RecyclerView` to take advantage of the features provided along with `toolbar`. This scroll effect only works with children of `NestedScrollingChild`

Comment: Cool :). Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try change from

```
local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

to

```
local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Comment: try adding nested scroll to your fragment. Check my edit

Comment: collapse toolbar layout only works with nested scroll. So you must have to use recycler view instead of list view. Recycler view has inbuilt nested scrolling....

Comment: Alright, I understand.. Since @sha stated this before you I'll accept his answer, but thanks for your help, I appreciate it.